# Return unique rows in list of dataframes

Tags: r, lapply

I have a list of dataframes. I'd like to find the unique rows in each dataframe, and then output that list of unique dataframes into 1 new dataframe.

Starting with `y <- list(mtcars[,c(2,4)], iris[,4:5])`

I first rename the columns within each dataframe

```
colnames <- c("colA", "colB")
y <- lapply(y, setNames, colnames)
```

To find the unique rows individually, I can use

```
y1 <- unique(y[[1]])
y2 <- unique(y[[2]])
```

But of course my list of dataframes is much larger, and I'd like to apply this across the entire list of ~100 dataframes.  How can I do this? I tried `lapply` but get an Error.

The dummy data above throws the error:

> Error in unique[[x]] : object of type 'closure' is not
> subsettable

and my real data throws the error:

> Error in mydf[[x]] : invalid subscript type 'list'

I know the last step of my process, to put everything into one big dataframe, is an `rbind` call (individually:`rbind(y1,y2)` , but I'm also not sure how to run `rbind` over that list of ~100 dataframe (that now only have non-duplicated rows)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each element in the list apply `unique` and then use `do.call` to combine the dataframes.

```
result <- do.call(rbind, lapply(y, unique))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can also use `distinct` with `map`

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
map_dfr(y, ~ distinct(.x) %>%
                 mutate(across(everything(), as.character)))
```